# PHP exec() . can i use this to export data to csv with a search criteria

Tags: php

PHP exec() . can i use this to export data to csv with a search criteria.

As the result is huge can i use exec and run system command as a parameter and return a result as csv or zip.

Is this possible??

Comment: http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php and http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. Here is a sample code we use to do daily MyQSL backup:

```
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
        $file = $path.$obj->base.".sql";
        $cmd = "rm -f ".$file;
        exec($cmd);
        $cmd = "nice -19 mysqldump -h".$host." -u".$login." -p".$pass." ".$obj->base." > ".$file;
        exec($cmd);
        $sql = "update save_mysql set last_daily=NOW() where base = '".$obj->base."'";
        mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wonty be able to return, hence the name Execute that's what its for just executing

You would be able to do something like:

```
exec('myzip some/file.csv > output.zip &');
```

Comment: Exec does not return the output (not all of it) but you can pass a second parameter into exec() and it will populate with the ouput.

Comment: But what you you populate it with, threre's nothing for the relevant situation, as its dealing with files but i did totally forget about the 2nd param.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a variable into the second argument of `exec`, this variable is an array which is filled with strings. One string for each line of output your shell command generates.

So if you do

```
// test.php
$data = array();
exec('ls', $data);
var_dump($data);
```

you will get output like this

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "foto1.psd"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "foto2.psd"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "tekening.psd"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "test.php"
}
```

After that you can populate a csv file as you would normally with php .. or do some post/prepocessing of the data before you output the csv. Take a look at [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: thanks ... i wil try ...if server is as 400 i shud know the as 400 commands ..is it??

Comment: what is the difference between system() and execute()